# mysql insert slows down considerable beyond a threshold

Tags: mysql, performance

I plan to insert about 100 million rows into my simple db table where the first column is indexed varchar(256) (see below col1), to make insertion faster, I issued a disable keys statement prior to insert.  so my process is like this:

```
alter table xxx disable keys;
insert ignore into xxx(col1, col2) values('a',1), values('b',1), values('c',1)...
alter table xxx enable keys;
```

I'm inserting 1 million at a time using the above statement(so about 1 million values pair).
The first 15 millions goes pretty fast and constant(within reasonable speed of 30 seconds per million), 
however, now I started another process of insertion of about only 1 mil into xxx, it takes forever(an hour into it and still has not finished). 

am I missing something?  does anything need to be tuned?

Comment: What takes the time, the insert or the `enable keys`?

Comment: Are any of the 2 columns part of a PRIMARY/UNIQUE index?

Comment: the insert takes time, enable keys was almost instant.  no, only the 1st column is an index(not a primary key, and not unique)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the mysql LOAD DATA INFILE command instead of individual inserts. This is typically much faster. Check out the documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Also, if this is a table you'll never update or delete data from, you could try converting the table to use the archive engine (instead of InnoDB or any others). This engine is made for storing massive amounts of records and is very fast to insert new records. Check this out for more:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/storage-engine.html